# Bug in TeXworks viewer?

Tags: texworks

I have recently updated a MikTeX distribution and getting a weird artifact when the pdf is viewed through the TeXworks default viewer. pdf looks normal in acrobat. The white lines shouldn't be there. Bug looks to me like due to the poppler library.

```
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\pagecolor{blue}
\begin{document}
\fboxrule2pt
\fbox{hello world is here}

\end{document}
```

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (MiKTeX 23.10.12)
 system commands enabled.
(./test-broken-poppler.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-06-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-10-23>
 ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/article.cls"
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/size10.clo"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty"
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/graphics/mathcolor.ltx"))
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def")
(./test-broken-poppler.aux)
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd")
("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) [1{C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/fonts/map/pdftex/pdftex.map}]
(./test-broken-poppler.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option)
  xcolor.sty    2022/06/12 v2.14 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
  luatex.def    2022/09/22 v1.2d Graphics/color driver for luatex
mathcolor.ltx
l3backend-luatex.def    2021-03-18 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
  ts1cmr.fd    2023/04/13 v2.5m Standard LaTeX font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********

)
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:50,3:4,4:14,5:44,6:2,7:72,9:58
<//?/c:/program files/miktex 2.9/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.otf
>
Output written on test-broken-poppler.pdf (1 page, 4137 bytes).
SyncTeX written on test-broken-poppler.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on test-broken-poppler.log.
```

[image]

Comment: It ight be an idea to also post an image of what it is suppose to look like.

Comment: @daleif   It is supposed to show just the blue. The white line on the right should not be there! Weird bug.

Comment: Is the fbox relevant or does the issue also show without it, i.e., `\pagecolor{blue}\begin{document}x\end{document}`?

Comment: @Marijn No it is not relevant, issue shows in both cases.

Comment: Do you see the same thing, if you change the magnification in TeXworks?

Comment: @rallg Yes is a very pronounced white line

Comment: This IS a slight difference, when PDF is viewed in TeXworks and in Evince (I am using Linux). If I set the paper color to red (in TeXworks) then I see a narrow red strip at the side. But same PDF, no red strip when viewed in Evince. This is not the same as what you see, but my software is very different, and may correspond to different versions (even if the same software).

Comment: @rallg Thanks for your comments. One would expect differences between viewers, but in my case is an annoying bug. I have been trying all sorts of things, also viewed the pdf to see differences etc.

Comment: I should have mentioned: On my machine (Linux) I can build using TeXworks, or via command line. Either way, solid blue, no mater whether I view in TeXworks or Evince. Only difference is that tiny border when viewed (which is a feature of TeXworks, not a bug). So, this appears specific to MiKTeX/Windows, or perhaps to versioning (my system usually has the most recent software).

Comment: @rallg yes definitely specific to the latest update from MikTeX. I normally use sublime3 to edit and compile. I only use TeXworks for dtx files. Sublime 3 is also available on Linux. I find it extremely fast. Thanks again.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing. A bug has been added at https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/1031 for it, but it seems it's a miktex issue, so my feeling is that's the wrong place for it.

Comment: @takrl I fixed it by downloading the TeXworks executable from github and installing it manually and the problem disappeared. IMHO problem was either MikTeX or the Poppler libraries.