MiKTeX installation takes forever

Hi all!
I needed to reinstall the MiKTeX installation. After uninstalling and trying to reinstall, I encountered a problem. The installation does not complete and remains in the state as in the photo. I tried installing in different directories several times, also waited for several hours, but at the specified moment the process slows down. I also deleted all files from ...\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX before reinstalling.
The message on the screen is the following:

extracting files from zapfchan.cab...


extracting files from zapfding.cab...


updating package manifests (C:\Users\john_dou\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex/config\package-manifests.ini)...


installed 6360 package manifests


visiting repository C:\Users\john_dou\AppData\Local\Temp\mik68414...


repository type: local package repository


loading package repository manifest...


165 [0x00005684] INFO initexmf null - this is MiKTeX Configuration Utility 5.3 (MiKTeX 23.4) 165 [0x00005684] INFO initexmf null - this process (7612) started by basic-miktex-23.4-x64 in directory C:\Distrib with command line: initexmf --principal=setup --user-install=C:\Users\john_dou\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX"--common-install=C:\Program Files\MiKTeX" -set-config-value=[Core] SharedSetup=0 --disable-installer verbose 166 [0x00005684] INFO initexmf null - Operating on the private (per-user) MiKTeX setup 166 [0x00005684] INFO initexmf null - Registering root directories... Registering root directories...


167 [0x00005684] INFO trace.initexmf.core null - saving startup configuration; setupVersion=23.4 171 [0x00005684] INFO initexmf null - Setting config value: [Core] SharedSetup=0 Setting config value: [Core]SharedSetup=0

I dont know what happens and why everything works before reinstalling but something perevent it from working now.
Appreciate any help.
Thanks in advance!

Hello, not really an answer and others may not agree with this, but I'd recommend TeXLive over MiKTeX. (1) MiKTeX has known issues with its TeXWorks editor: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700093/bug-in-texworks-viewer (2) MiKTeX uses an outdated GhostScript installation, making Asymptote a pain in the back to use, and I think I'm forgetting one other reason.
