Issues with Tikz in Preview Window of TeXworks
I'm using TeXworks with MiKTeX to compile my document and I've encountered a strange issue in the preview window. There appears to be a garbled display at the right edge of a blue rectangle (a white gap appears). Interestingly, this problem doesn't occur when I view the document in Acrobat; it only shows up in the preview.
Has anyone experienced similar issues, and what could be causing this? How can I fix this problem in the TeXworks preview?
Thank you for your help!
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,xcolor,microtype}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec} 
\usepackage{physics}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{xstring}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
% Background gradient fill`
% Rectangle on the left (coordinates from northwest of the page)
\fill[blue,draw=black]
($ (current page.north west) + (0cm, -4cm) $) rectangle
($ (current page.north west) + (1cm, -1cm) $);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]{Introduction}
Further simplification involves our fifth and final assumption, which can
be argued with two special cases of great interest.
\end{frame}


\end{document}



You either need to install the texworks from github and use that, or use tex live. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/700093/bug-in-texworks-viewer. This is a problem with the miktex release.

https://www.tug.org/texworks/#Getting_TeXworks

@Jasper Hi. It is a old problem. I have written on github, but yet it has yet solved. Why? TeXworks has been updating after my issue in github but the ugly rendering with TeXworks yet exists. It is not a bug of TeXworks: https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1520, https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/1435, https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/1037.

@Sebastiano, The problem seems to be with the MikTeX version of TeXWorks. If you switch distributions to TeXLive it should go away. If you want to stick with MiKTeX, then download a working TeXWorks from https://www.tug.org/texworks/#Getting_TeXworks
